# get list of all matching string from another list of strings in scala

Tags: scala

In Scala how to get a list of all strings which match one of the patterns in another string. for example, I have two lists

```
lst1=["a/b/d=20180103","a/c/d=20180201","a/c/d=20180102","a/e/d=20180104","a/b/d=20180203"]

lst2 = ["20180102", "20180103", "20180104"]
```

now I need the intersection of `list1` which match patterns from `list2`.

expected output:

```
["a/b/d=20180103", "a/c/d=20180102","a/e/d=20180104"]
```

Comment: Please do not tag languages that have nothing to do with your question.

Comment: I have tried this and it worked (item <- dataLst2){
    for(r <- rng if item.endsWith(r)) println(item) 
}

Answer (score 2):

Why not just `filter` it?

```
lst1.filter(s => lst2.exists(s.contains))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using simple for loop in scala i.e using a map on both the lists.

Have a look at the code below for a better understanding:-

```
val lst1 =List("a/b/d=20180103","a/c/d=20180201","a/c/d=20180102","a/e/d=20180104","a/b/d=20180203")

val lst2 = List("20180102", "20180103", "20180104")

val ans = lst1.map { value =>
  val firstPart = value.split('=').head
  val secondPart = value.split('=').last
  if(lst2.contains(secondPart)) {
    value
  } else {
    None
  }
}

ans.filter(_ != None)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collect` on the first list with a `case` partial function that retains those elements whose date substring is in the second list:

```
val lst1 = List("a/b/d=20180103", "a/c/d=20180201", "a/c/d=20180102", "a/e/d=20180104", "a/b/d=20180203")
val lst2 = List("20180102", "20180103", "20180104")

lst1.collect{ case s if lst2.contains(s.split("=").last) => s }
// res1: List[String] = List(a/b/d=20180103, a/c/d=20180102, a/e/d=20180104)
```